# Proving If a is an odd integer then $a^2+3a+5$ is odd.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, parity

I've written a proof for which looks correct, but I wanted to know it from someone else as well. Also I feel like my proof could be made a bit shorter, so if anyone has advice for that I would appreciate it!

Suppose that $a$ is odd. Therefore $a=2n+1$. We can write the expression as $(2n+1)^2+6n+3+5$. $(2n+1)^2= (2n)^2+4n+1^2+6n+3+5$.
After rearranging the terms we get: $(2n)^2+10n+9$.

We can see that both $(2n)^2$ and $10n$ is even, so $(2n)^2=2k$ and $10n=2m$. After substituting we get $2k+2m+9$. Finally we write this as $2(k+m)+9$, which is even + odd and that is odd.

Comment: If $a$ is odd , $a^2$ , $3a$ and $5$ are all odd, so they sum up to an odd number.

Comment: For any $a$, $a^2+3a = a(a+3)$ is even, since either $a$ or $a+3$ is even. Hence, adding $5$ gives an odd number.

Comment: Furthermore, $a^2+3a+2$ is always even, making the number always odd.

Comment: @UmeshShankar Why "furthermore"? isn't it the same as Didier's comment?

Comment: @AnneBauval I think our comments were published at the same moment

Comment: To be more explicit, write the expression as $(a+1)(a+2)+3$. One of $a+1,a+2$ is even, so the  product is even and adding 3 makes it odd.

Answer (score 2):

odd x odd=odd,  odd+odd=even,  even+odd = odd . When $a$ is odd, $$a^2+3a+5=\text{odd x odd + odd x odd + odd}$$ $$=\text {odd + odd + odd}$$$$=\text {even + odd}$$ $$=\text{odd}.$$

Answer (score 1):

It's fine, though I would have carried the second paragraph a few steps further:

$$
\begin{align}
... &= (2n)^2+4n+1^2+6n+3+5 \\
&= 4n^2 + 10n + 9 \\
& = 2(2n^2+5n+4) +1 
\end{align}
$$

and that is one of the definitions of "odd", i.e. "can be written as $2k+1$ for some integer $k$", so you are done.

It's basically the same argument you've used. I just think it's organized a bit more neatly/clearly, and doesn't introduce those extra variables ($k$ and $m$) that are barely used.